# Can't call native iOS method from React Native

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, pusher

I want to subscribe to push notifications for the Pusher service for a particular channel, but because the react native Pusher client doesn't support push notifications, I need to write a bridge.

To this end, there's a native iOS method called 'subscribe' I want to call on an instance(?) of 'pusher' from react native, but for some reason it won't execute properly.

'pusher' is intialised in AppDelegate.m as:

```
self.pusher = [PTPusher pusherWithKey:@"..." delegate:self encrypted:YES cluster:@"ap1"];
```

The exported native iOS function in AppDelegate.m I've written looks like:

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(subscribe:(NSString *)channel) {
  [[[self pusher] nativePusher] subscribe:channel];
  NSLog(@"Called AppDelegate.subscribe with channel: %@", channel);
}
```

which I call in react native using NativeModules.AppDelegate.subscribe([channel]). I can see this is being called because the log shows up, but I can tell that the nativePusher.subscribe function isn't being called because notifications don't get received, and the logging I've added within nativePusher.subscribe doesn't show up.

The strange thing is that the nativePusher.subscribe method works if it's called under a different function:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
  [[[self pusher] nativePusher] registerWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];
  NSLog(@"Registered device token: %@", deviceToken);
  [[[self pusher] nativePusher] subscribe:@"channelc"];
}
```

So I suspect it's something to do with the

> application:(UIApplication *)application

not being used, and/or the reference to self.

Do I need to call nativePusher.subscribe differently because I'm exporting it to react native or is it something else?